# How to delete rows in multiple columns by unique number?

Tags: r

Given data like this

```
C1<-c(3,-999.000,4,4,5)
C2<-c(3,7,3,4,5)
C3<-c(5,4,3,6,-999.000)
DF<-data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"),C1=C1,C2=C2,C3=C3)
```

How do I go about removing the -999.000 data in all of the columns

I know this works per column

```
DF2<-DF[!(DF$C1==-999.000 | DF$C2==-999.000 | DF$C3==-999.000),]
```

But I'd like to avoid referencing each column. I am thinking there is an easy way to reference all of the columns in a particular data frame aka:

```
DF3<-DF[!(DF[,]==-999.000),]
```

or

```
DF3<-DF[!(DF[,(2:4)]==-999.000),]
```

but obviously these do not work

And out of curiosity, bonus points if you can me why I need that last comma before the ending square bracket as in:

```
==-999.000),]
```

Comment: To remark on an answer- I can have multiple -999 values in a given row

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following may work

```
DF[!apply(DF==-999,1,sum),]
```

or if you can have multiple -999 on a row

```
DF[!(apply(DF==-999,1,sum)>0),]
```

or

```
DF[!apply(DF==-999,1,any),]
```

Comment: loving the any function as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To address your "bonus" question, if we go to the documentation for `?Extract.data.frame` we will find:

> Data frames can be indexed in several modes. When `[` and `[[` are used
>   with a single index (`x[i]` or `x[[i]]`), they index the data frame as if
>   it were a list. In this usage a drop argument is ignored, with a
>   warning.

and also:

> When `[` and `[[` are used with two indices (`x[i, j]` and `x[[i, j]]`) they
>   act like indexing a matrix: `[[` can only be used to select one element.
>   Note that for each selected column, `xj` say, typically (if it is not
>   matrix-like), the resulting column will be `xj[i]`, and hence rely on
>   the corresponding `[` method, see the examples section.

So you need the comma to ensure that R knows you are referring to a row, not a column.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your code, I'll assume that you want to remove all rows that contain -999.

```
DF2 <- DF[rowSums(DF == -999) == 0, ]
```

As for your bonus question: A data frame is a list of vectors, all of which have the same length. If we think of the vectors as columns, then a data frame can be thought of as a matrix where the columns might have different types (numeric, character, etc). R allows you to refer to elements of a data frame much the same way you refer to elements of a matrix; by using row and column indices. So `DF[i, j]` refers to the `i`th element in the `j`th vector of DF, which you can think of as the `i`th row and `j`th column. So if you want to retain only some of the rows of the data frame and all columns, you can use a matrix-like notation: `DF[row.indices, ]`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand if your target is to remove all the rows that contain at least one NA, if this is what you are looking for, then this could be a possible answer:

```
DF[DF==-999] <- NA
na.omit(DF)
   ID C1 C2 C3
1  A  3  3  5
3  C  4  3  3
4  D  4  4  6
```