# R remove rows containing a certain value

Tags: r, dataframe

So it got a csv I'm reading into an R dataframe, it looks like this

```
clientx,clienty,screenx,screeny
481,855,481,847
481,784,481,847
481,784,481,847
879,292,879,355
```

First line is of course the header. So we have 4 columns with numeric data in it, ranging from 1 to 4 digits. There are no negative numbers in the set except -1 which marks a missing value.
I want to remove every row that contains a -1 in any of the 4 columns.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974404/how-to-delete-rows-in-multiple-columns-by-unique-number

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your most efficient way will be to use the `na.strings` argument of `read.csv()` to code all `-1` values as `NA`, then to drop incomplete cases.

---

**Step 1:** set `na.strings=-1` in `read.csv()`:

```
x <- read.csv(text="
clientx,clienty,screenx,screeny
481,855,481,847
481,784,481,847
481,784,481,847
-1,292,879,355", header=TRUE, na.strings=-1)

x
clientx clienty screenx screeny
1     481     855     481     847
2     481     784     481     847
3     481     784     481     847
4      NA     292     879     355
```

---

**Step 2:** Now use `complete.cases` or `na.omit`:

```
x[complete.cases(x), ]
  clientx clienty screenx screeny
1     481     855     481     847
2     481     784     481     847
3     481     784     481     847

na.omit(x)
  clientx clienty screenx screeny
1     481     855     481     847
2     481     784     481     847
3     481     784     481     847
```

---

Answer (score 8):

The direct way:

```
df <- df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) {any(x == -1)}),]
```

UPDATE: this approach will fail if data.frame contains character columns because `apply` implicitly converts data.frame to matrix (which contains data of only one type) and character type has a priority over numeric types thus data.frame will be converted into character matrix.

Or replace -1 with `NA` and then use `na.omit`:

```
df[df==-1] <- NA
df <- na.omit(df)
```

These should work, I didn't check. Please always try to provide a reproducible example to illustrate your question.